# Having problems with changing SharedPreferences value

Tags: java, android

I want to save a value ("Coins"), and I'm using the SharedPreferences option (I want that the number of coins will be saved even after closing the app).
I used 2 functions, one to insert (/change) the coins number, and another one to get it. In addition, I made a button which after clicking on it, it changes the number of the coins. The problem is, that the button doesn't change it. Any help? Thanks in advance.

```
package com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnPlay;

public void changeCoinsNumber(String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("PlayerInfo", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public int loadCoinsNumber(String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("PlayerInfo", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int savedValue = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0);
    return savedValue;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    changeCoinsNumber("CoinsNumber", 5);

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spText);
    txt.setText(""+loadCoinsNumber("CoinsNumber")); // displaying the number of coins

    btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeCoinsNumber("CoinsNumber", 111);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: All the things look fine. Did u checked the shared preference after pressing the button to know that the value has not changed?

Comment: Good idea, though Neo helped me. Thank you!

Comment: @GauravJindal, do you know if it will keep the info after closing the app?

Comment: Yes it will. Actually whatever u store in shared preference is saved in a file within ur app's folder in data folder on internal storage. As it is saved in file, the data will be available all the time.

Comment: @GauravJindal Great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to display it again if you change the coins value as per you code. I am updating a small portion of your code.

```
    final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spText);//Make txt final
    txt.setText(""+loadCoinsNumber("CoinsNumber")); // displaying the number of coins

    btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeCoinsNumber("CoinsNumber", 111);
            txt.setText(""+loadCoinsNumber("CoinsNumber"));//Adding this line to update
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks @Neo! Helping me again :) Thank you! (I would have upvote, but I don't have enough reputation...)

Comment: what is the "final" in the TextView for? What's the difference between puting it as "public" in the beginning of the code?

Comment: Yes you can do it also, but if it is not a class level variable then you need to make it final to access within an inner class. 
Is it working for you ?

Comment: Yes, thank you :) Another question (if I may) - when I closing the app, the number of coins sets back to 5. How do I make my changes permanent?

Comment: Then write it in onDestroy, protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        changeCoinsNumber("CoinsNumber", 5);
    }
+1, please accept the best answer :)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to +1 for you :( Need 15... And, what's that onDestroy? can you explain please? thanks!

Comment: onDestroy() is called when an activity finishes its life cycle. It is also called once in the lifecycle of an activity.

You can still accept this answer :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw. Did it now :) And OK, that sounds good. But if I want it to keep my last value, and then present it? I mean, for the first time the app runs - it will give it 5, after the button is clicked, it will change to 111, and after we close and open the app again, it will still be 111 (or any other number, last one that we keeped). Thanks again :)

Comment: Then if you need default value 5 then no need to store actually, just you need to change in loadCoinNumber, int savedValue = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 5); //just change 0 to 5. Then if no data will be there then it will return 5.

Comment: Default only for the first time the app runs, not the default everytime the app runs. Any idea what could help in this situation? And btw, what is the second value in this line? (the "5") savedValue = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 5);

Comment: Yes the second value is for default, if you have never saved any value using the key, then it will return this value. And it works for first time only. If you need to change on every launch, then you need to save in onCreate/onDestory .

Comment: Ok, thank you for your info. I got what I want, it's working! :) Thank you very much Neo! Can't upvote you enough...